# MS Word ExportAsFixedFormat(..) throws Exception 80070057

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to automate the print2PDF procedure in Microsoft Word for use with Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

I created this macro which is executed when the user has a document opened and says "Print to PDF":

```
Sub Main
    'On Error GoTo errorHandler

    Set wApp = GetObject(,"Word.Application")

    If wApp.Documents.Count >= 1 Then
        wApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName :="tst1.pdf", _
        ExportFormat := wdExportFormatPDF, _
        UseISO19005_1 := True
    Else
        MsgBox "Kein Dokument geöffnet"
    End If
    Set wApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

    errorHandler:
    MsgBox "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Kontaktieren Sie Helpdesk."
    Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

However upon execution I always get Error 80070057. I googled the error code and it says "invalid arguements", but I can't explain that since I've been following the steps in this MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/document-exportasfixedformat-method-word to the letter. Do you have any idea what I could try to get past the error?

Workarounds I've tried:
Using SaveAs and SaveAs2 don't work either, they always ignore the Format I require (wdFormatPDF) and save the document as docx. The only thing that works to some extent is to set ActivePrinter as print2pdf and then use the PrinOut method, but it gives me a printer dialog, which I don't want.

Comment: Are you able to save to PDF as a user - does the functionality actually work on your installation? Which version of Word?

Comment: I am able to save a word coument as PDF using File->Save As-> filename.pdf, yes.

Comment: We are using Office 2016

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) Provide a full path with the file name for `OutputFilename` ; 2) Try removing the last argument completely since it's optional. But I suspect it may well be the file path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by your use of late binding with named arguments (which requires early binding). Instead of:

wApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName :="tst1.pdf", _
        ExportFormat := wdExportFormatPDF, UseISO19005_1 := True

try:

wApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat "tst1.pdf", 17, , , , , , , , , , , , True